# Glsl how to achieve a color into a certain color?

Tags: glsl

I want to do a function that makes the white in a picture gray, but I failed

Here's the code

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec4 vColor;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
uniform float customUniform;

void main(void)
{
    vec2 r = vTextureCoord;
    vec4 tex = texture2D(uSampler,r);

    if(tex.r==1.0 && tex.g==1.0 && tex.b==1.0){
       tex.r=0.3;
       tex.g=0.3;
       tex.b=0.3;
    }
    gl_FragColor = tex;
}
```

this show White edge

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the white line in the picture is almost white, not completely white. You need to check against a threshold:

```c
if (tex.r > 0.9 && tex.g > 0.9 && tex.b > 0.9)
{
    tex.r = 0.3;
    tex.g = 0.3;
    tex.b = 0.3;
}
```

Alternatively, with the use of [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling), [`greaterThan`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/greaterThan.xhtml) and [`all`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/all.xhtml):

```c
if (all(greaterThan(tex.rgb, vec3(0.9))))
    tex.rgb = vec3(0.3);
```

Another solution should check whether the sum of the color channels exceeds a certain limit:

```c
if (dot(tex.rgb, vec3(1.0)) / 3.0 > 0.9)
    tex.rgb = vec3(0.3);
```

Or whether the color vector exceeds a certain length:

```c
if (length(tex.rgb) > 1.6)
    tex.rgb = vec3(0.3);
```